# React: Array length changes not triggering re-render in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

in react, I have a list of topics, each with a nested list of sets. The topics render the length of sets, and the sets. Occasionally I need to move a set from one topic to another. I can get the sets to re-render after moving correctly, but the set length won't visually change. I believe this is an issue with mutating the state, but I believe I compensate for that my copying my topics array with this.state.Topics.slice() before any changes to it.

TopicList.js

```
ChangeSetsTopic(event)
{
    var sourceTopic;
    var topics = this.state.Topics.slice();


   sourceTopic = topics.find(obj => {return obj.Topic == event.source.droppableId});

    var change_set;
    for (var i =  sourceTopic["Sets"].length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (sourceTopic["Sets"][i].SetID == event.draggableId) {
            change_set = sourceTopic["Sets"].splice(i,1)[0];
        }
    }

    var destinationTopic = topics.find(obj => {return obj.Topic == event.destination.droppableId});


    destinationTopic["Sets"].push(change_set);


    for (var i = 0 ; i < topics.length ; i++) {
        if (topics[i].Topic == sourceTopic.Topic) {
            topics[i] = sourceTopic;
        }
        else if (topics[i].Topic == destinationTopic.Topic) {
            topics[i] = destinationTopic;
        }
    }

   this.setState({"Topics" : topics });

    

}
```

```
    render(){ 
return( {this.state.Topics.map(( topic , key ) => (
            <Topic key={topic.Topic} Sets={topic.Sets} TopicName={topic.Topic}/>
      ))}
);}
```

Topic.js

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.Sets.length.toString() != this.props.Sets.toString() ) 
        {
          this.setState({"Sets" : this.props.Sets })
        }
      }
```

```
render(){
return( ... <div>this.state.Sets.length.toString()</div> ...)
}
```

Comment: This `prevProps.Sets.length.toString() != this.props.Sets.toString()` doesn't seem correct

Comment: There is no such thing as a react array

Comment: I am not claiming this is a react array, react is present in my title to indicate the stack I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has no idea that by calling `destinationTopic["Sets"].push(change_set);` mutates the state of another component. It is recommended that your components be as stateless as possible and that your data come from a single source that then propagates down your chain. I'd recommend looking into the [Flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview), as this will help you better understand how data flows through React without internal state. One implementation of Flux is [Redux](http://redux.js.org)

If you are set on mutating state the way you are, then I would recommend looking into [Mobx](http://mobx.js.org) since what you have will work out of the box using Mobx stores.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response. Switching to a Flux architecture has so far cleaned things up and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Topics` array changing and React can see it updated, but it can't see individual items in array updated, items are objects, React compares objects by reference, not by content, so it can't see changes there.

E.g. `destinationTopic` is an object.